# deflate zlib from a sqlite android database

Tags: android, sqlite, gmail, zlib

im trying to uncompress the data retrieve from sqlite gmail database to do some triggers. How can i do this?

This is the output from bodyCompressed.

```
pë☼IìÑ61UX 4×►▒▒ü4`¼┬♠6~ó©DX?┴¯╠ß1╝Q.
Cmhs↓×♥ògS'â%ÅÙÅDR½òÙ%Á┌┐e"Ì↓fÚp§Y7±[±☻¸h"X
```

You can see on this image

[image]

I need to do this in terminal but i dont know what can i do.

**EDIT ADDING HEX**

```
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
```

[image]

**EDITED WITH JAVA CODE TRYING THIS**

```
private String getTextMail(){
String mail="";
Process sh = null;
try {
    sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
try {
    os.write(("sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.romapudelca@gmail.com.db \"SELECT bodyCompressed FROM MESSAGES WHERE dateSentMs=(SELECT max(dateSentMs) from messages)\"").getBytes("ASCII"));
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    InputStream is=sh.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }
    Inflater decompresser = new Inflater(true);
    decompresser.setInput(buffer.toByteArray());
    byte[] result = new byte[4096];
    int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
    decompresser.end();
    sh.waitFor();
    mail=new String(result);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DataFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return mail;
}
```

**Java code return me this:**

```
W/System.err: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths
W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:214)
W/System.err:     at cpc.cpc_dectect.MainActivity$telegramTask$override.getTextMail(MainActivity.java:229)
W/System.err:     at cpc.cpc_dectect.MainActivity$telegramTask$override.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:249)
W/System.err:     at cpc.cpc_dectect.MainActivity$telegramTask$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
W/System.err:     at cpc.cpc_dectect.MainActivity$telegramTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:0)
W/System.err:     at cpc.cpc_dectect.MainActivity$telegramTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:196)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**ERROR USING PRINTF MODE**

```
\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - fich.gz| gzip -d                                   <
<div dir="ltr"><div>bla bla bla bl abl abla</div><div><br></div><d
iv><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>Links:</div><div><br></div>    <div>
┬á 1. <a href="https://arpo.com/2asajshkdashjkashdjka0a gzip: failed gz
close
```

*If i use -dc params in gzip the system returns:*

```
-dc: No such file or directory
sush: cat: <stdout>: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Are you sure this is zlib data? Show a [hex](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) dump of the value.

Comment: Why must it be in a terminal? Can't you use Java code?

Comment: Cause i cant get it using java. I have added the errors.

Comment: Why the detour through `sqlite3`? Why don't you read the blob directly from the database?

Answer (score 1):

In the `sqlite3` command-line shell, you can use the [writefile() function](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions) to put the blob into a file:

```
SELECT writefile('body.zlib', SomeColumn) FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = 42;
```

Then [use `gzip` or `openssl` or `zlib-flate` or a Python script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22834/23071) to decompress this file:

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - body.zlib | gzip -dc
```

```
openssl zlib -d < body.zlib
```

```
zlib-flate -uncompress < body.zlib
```

```py
import zlib
import sys

with open('body.zlib', 'rb') as compressed:
    with open('body.txt', 'wb') as expanded:
        data = zlib.decompress(compressed.read())
        expanded.write(data)
```

Comment: When i use "printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - body.zlib | gzip -dc" returns to me "broken pipe" ON ANDROID.

Comment: Im using the printf format but gzip returns me an error(you can see it in the post)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the file, you can just read the value directly from Java:

```java
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
    "/data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.romapudelca@gmail.com.db",
    null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
try {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT bodyCompressed FROM ...", null);
    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = c.getBlob(0);

            // ... decompress the blob ...
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
} finally {
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: I have access the file through the terminal as "superuser" cause the device is rooted but i cant access through another app.